# understanding this binary file format and converting to base64

Tags: encoding, base64

I'm connecting to an API server, and the GET is retrieving a strange format, which I'm not sure what it is. Below is a sample.

`REQUEST:  GET /server/dab.png`

The response starts with:

`�PNG

IHDR`

bS��%�1�}F�8�1!h������]*��%h8kd��c�q�����6�d��J�ӊ�$����H��],JLQ�Q��1kC̔�$D�m0�b'f�F��W�o��P���fd���5��<�p��R����U��

How do I save it as a file on my local machine?

I do know how to save base64 string of a file to a file on my machine, but not sure what the current format is, and how to convert it to base64.

I'm using Javascript and have tried to play around with `window.btoa(str);` but with no success.

I'm using NodeJS to make a GET call and save it to my local machine.

Comment: What do the headers show, and what does your request look like?

Comment: We're going to need more info than that I think, especially seeing as half the bytes you've posted have been replaced with a substitute char. My guess would be the server is sending you compressed or encrypted data

Comment: Okay, it looks like it's a png file. It's not text, and you shoudln't try to display or read it as text. It's not clear why you'd want to base64-encode that, rather than just saving the data directly to a png file. Unfortunately it's hard to know how to help you as we don't know anything about your code, including what language you're using.

Comment: This is simply a byte stream of a PNG file. In MIME terms it is application/octet-stream . It is not base64 encoded nor should it be.

Comment: How do I save it to the local machine from a byte stream?

Comment: also updated the language and method of my GET call and saving it to db.

Comment: Alright,I understand it now. I'll just use `writeFile` to save it to the machine.